# Javascript: import a variable (object) into a constructor / option setter

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this Highchart constructor / option setter:

```
function drawChart(chart_lang) {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
                lang: {
                    loading: 'In caricamento...',
                    months: ['Gennaio','Febbraio','Marzo','Aprile','Maggio','Giugno','Luglio','Agosto','Settembre','Ottobre','Novembre','Dicembre'],
                    weekdays: ['Domenica','Lunedi','Martedi','Mercoledi','Giovedi','Venerdi','Sabato'],
                    shortMonths: ['Gen','Feb','Mar','Apr','Mag','Giu','Lug','Ago','Set','Ott','Nov','Dic'],
                    exportButtonTitle: 'Esporta',
                    printButtonTitle: 'Stampa',
                    rangeSelectorFrom: 'Da',
                    rangeSelectorTo: 'A',
                    rangeSelectorZoom: 'Zoom',
                    downloadPNG: 'Download PNG',
                    downloadJPEG: 'Download JPEG',
                    downloadPDF: 'Download PDF',
                    downloadSVG: 'Download SVG',
                    printChart: 'Stampa',
                    resetZoom: 'Reset'
               }
        });

    $('div#grow').highcharts({

            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },

     // other stuffs...


}
```

I recall this function in this mode:

```
var chart_lang = {

        lang: {
                loading: 'In caricamento...',
                months: ['Gennaio','Febbraio','Marzo','Aprile','Maggio','Giugno','Luglio','Agosto','Settembre','Ottobre','Novembre','Dicembre'],
                weekdays: ['Domenica','Lunedi','Martedi','Mercoledi','Giovedi','Venerdi','Sabato'],
                shortMonths: ['Gen','Feb','Mar','Apr','Mag','Giu','Lug','Ago','Set','Ott','Nov','Dic'],
                exportButtonTitle: "Esporta",
                printButtonTitle: "Stampa",
                rangeSelectorFrom: "Da",
                rangeSelectorTo: "A",
                rangeSelectorZoom: "Zoom",
                downloadPNG: 'Download PNG',
                downloadJPEG: 'Download JPEG',
                downloadPDF: 'Download PDF',
                downloadSVG: 'Download SVG',
                printChart: 'Stampa',
                resetZoom: 'Reset'
        }

    };

    if ($('div#grow').length>0) {

        drawGrowChart(chart_lang);

    }
```

Could I use the `chart_lang` variable//object insted of rewrite in the drawChart() ?

Thank you

Comment: `Highcharts.setOptions(chart_lang)` should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: better to use configurable object

Comment: @apokryfos it works... my mistake was tring with the {}. Thank you!

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN can you explain, please? THank you!

Comment: @sineverba So the problem is resolved? If it is not, than please provide more info.